# "Kontakt" vs. "Impressum"

Tags: english-to-german, difference

I am building a contact page for a website that caters to a German audience and was wondering which word makes more sense for a "contact us" page.

I was browsing various websites in Germany and noticed that they have those two different words for same type of page.

Please note that the website is for a medical manufacturing company.

Comment: *Kontakt* is where larger sites could provide a contact form or (email) address, store locator, maps etc., but some just try to guide the user to a FAQ there, so as to reduce manual support costs. *Impressum* has to provide a valid physical address and more for legal reasons. It’s often useful to include the imprint within the contact page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A contact page is a page designed to give your users the opportunity to contact you.

An **Impressum** is a page that fulfills the legal requirements of Germany and people the opportunity to contact the people responsible for the site. ON big site there might be different addresses for webmaster and so on.

You are required by law to have an "Impressum". It may vary in content depending what kind of site you are having but the lack of an impressum or a page that contains the respecitive information can lead to high fines. You should definitely take care there and maybe consider getting legal advice.

Most if not all bigger businesses have both pages so I'd recommend doing so too.

Comment: I highly doubt that every country requires you to have an impressum (even Germany only does this for certain sites).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft... I meant only Germany actually... thanks for catching that

Comment: @Wrzlprmft the site is in the medical industry. Would that make a difference?

Comment: @JGallardo.. you need to pay attention there and do it right. Maybe do some search or see if you can ask in a legal board. Companies have been fined thousands for a missing line.

Comment: @JGallardo: If the site is commercial, having an *Impressum* is a good idea anyway – be it legally required or not. I only did not want the common misbelief uncorrected that **every** site must have an Impressum stand uncorrected.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft... as far as I know, actually every site must have one... even "Familie-Schmidt.de"

Comment: @Emanuel: as far as I know, you need to have an Impressum in case of commercial or journalistic content - but that's a pretty broad concept and could be triggered by having ads, blogging, a book recommendation, etc; so better err on the side of caution

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Note that an imprint is *required* for **every** web site in Germany! Only the content differs between private and commercial sites. To avoid legal consequences, you **must** include an imprint.

Comment: May I suggest that we remove all legal advice (except for a caveat to legally inform oneself in general)? Due to the changes of question and answer it is not clear anymore, e.g., what refers to commercial and similar use and what doesn’t.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft... I modified my answer a bit. However, I don't see why we should totally avoid saying that there is a legal requirement. I mean so long as we don't give a sample text that could contain compromising mistakes, we're doing nothing wrong, are we

Comment: @Emanuel: If your statement is sufficiently vague, you can do nothing wrong – but then again it’s not useful to anybody. That’s why I would resort to just mentioning that a legal requirement exists in most cases (or quoting somebody else like Thorsten Dittmar did), but do nothing more.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft In Austria it's actually the case. Even for private pages. If you don't have an Impressum you could be sued. Something competitors like to do. It's cheap for them to report you and you have to pay a view thousend euros.

Comment: "and it must be labeled as such as far as I know": No, you are not required to label it "Impressum". The [law](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/tmg/__5.html) calls it "Informationspflichten", but it doesn’t require a special label, it just has to be easy to recognize/find.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft... I changed it again? What's your opinion?

Comment: legally it is necessary, but only for germans. (just out of practicabilty, a german could sue a german for not having an impressum, but if he tried to sue an american the us justice department would laugh at him ;-)

Comment: @RRZEurope... I think citizenship doesn't matter. Server location does, and location of your main target group. So if you market from Germany to Germans and you have an American passport you'll have to abide by German law.

Comment: @Emanuel you are right, the server location only is of importance. From the german law an american with an american server reaching german audience would also have to have an impressum, but there is no way that it could be enforced unless the american justice makes some kind of partnership with the germans (and there is no reason why they should do such a thing)

Comment: But if only the server is in the US, but the responsible one is in Germany, the German justice will have no trouble enforcing it, even if the responsible one is an American citizen.

Answer (score 11):

German law regulates that **every** web site (be it commercial or private) must contain an imprint that can be viewed using a "reasonable number of clicks" (<strike>whatever that means...</strike> details in the below edit). Only the content (required information) given in the imprint may vary between private and commercial sites. There are "imprint generators" on the web which create an imprint for you based on information you fill in.

I quote the ["Bundesministerium der Justiz und für Verbraucherschutz"](http://www.bmj.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/DE/pdfs/LeitfadenZurAnbieterkennzeichnung.pdf;jsessionid=7E6B374028EFD880B4DAF672032972EC.1_cid289?__blob=publicationFile):

> Die Anbieterkennzeichnungspflicht muss praktisch von jedem, der ein Online-Angebot 
>   bereithält, erfüllt werden. Etwas anderes gilt nur bei Angeboten, die ausschließlich privaten oder familiären Zwecken dienen und die keine Auswirkung auf den Markt haben. 
>   Im Zweifel sollten Sie davon ausgehen, dass die Anbieterkennzeichnungspflicht 
>   besteht.

This quote sounds like private pages *should*  contain an imprint, but don't have to. However, earlier in the same document it says:

> Diensteanbieter sind nach §2 Satz 1 Nummer 1 TMG natürliche oder juristische Personen, die eigene oder fremde Telemedien zur Nutzung bereit halten oder den Zugang zur Nutzung vermitteln [...] So ist praktisch jeder Online-Auftritt ein Telemedium.
>   * Telemedien sind zum beispiel private Websites und Blogs, Online-Shops, [...]

While an imprint is mandatory, a contact page is not! The imprint must contain information on how to contact the owner of the site, so there's already a way to contact you. Most pages, however, contain more convenient ways like a contact form.

---

As requested:

The document I linked to above says

> § 5 Absatz 1 TMG gibt vor, dass die Angaben leicht erkennbar, unmittelbar erreichbar und ständig verfügbar gehalten werden müssen.

It explains "unmittelbar erreichbar" as:

> Unmittelbar erreichbar sind Angaben, die ohne wesentliche Zwischenschritte aufgerufen 
>   werden können. Nach der Rechtsprechung des BGH kann als gesichert gelten, dass das Erreichen einer Internetseite über zwei Links in der Regel kein langes Suchen erfordert und als unmittelbar gilt.

Comment: I'll provide a different quote in addition.

Comment: Can you cite where "reasonable number of clicks" can be found? I am a web developer and I'm wondering if I can include the Impressum and any other legal documents inside of my side bar navigation which is accessible form every page.

Comment: Yes, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: but that applies only to german citizens...

Comment: @RRZEurope no it doesn't. An American passport does not equal immunity

Comment: @RRZEurope That doesn't have to do with citizenship, I guess, but I'm not an Internet lawyer. That kind of discussion seems to be out of scope of this forum.

Comment: If Taka-Tuka-Land decides that the use of the letter 'A' on a webpage is forbidden, it is of no relevance for you, as long as you dont live in Taka-Tuka-Land. Therefore: if you are german, you have to have an impressum, if not, what could anyone in germany do, if you didnt put an impressum with your address in Taka-Tuka-Land onto it?

Comment: Well, if you want to do business in Taka-Tuka-Land, you better stick to their rules. As I said I'm not a lawyer. I just quoted what's being said in the Telemediengesetz.